# Average of Numbers in Column If Condition In Different Column Satisfied

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a data range of which the first column are dates and the second column are numerical values. There are some rows where the second column value is blank and I do not want them to be counted.

I am trying to find the average of the second column values if they satisfy the criteria of being within 3 months ago from today (blank values should not be counted).

But I am stuck as I cannot even get the total correct. And I do not know how to proceed further to get the average.

The code belows seem to give me appended strings instead of summing up the numbers mathematically.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance.

```
 function average() {
   // open spreadsheet
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID");
   // set the named sheet as active
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SheetName"));

   // figure out what the last row is
   var lastRow = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1").getLastRow();
   // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row is the headers, so start with row 2
   var startRow = 2;
   // get the data range
   var responsesValues = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1").getRange("A1:Q" + lastRow).getValues();

   // define the dates
   var timeToday = new Date().getTime();
   var dateToday = new Date().getDate();
   var date = new Date();
   var threeMonthsAgo = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - 3, 0);

   // grab column 1 (date of entry column) (second variable in getRange function below)
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
   var numRows = dataRange.getNumRows();
   var dateOfEntryValues = dataRange.getValues();

   // grab column 2 (values to be averaged)
   range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
   var Values = range.getValues();

   var warning_count = 0;
   var sumValues = 0;

   // Loop over the values
   for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
     var dateOfEntry = dateOfEntryValues[i][0];
     if(dateOfEntry > threeMonthsAgo && dateOfEntry !== "") {
   // if it's within 3 months ago, add the values.
   sumValues += Values[i][0];
   warning_count++;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot more simple version. Just put into the Destination Cell the formula

=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(IF(DATEDIF(C1:C;TODAY();"D")<=90;E1:E)))

replacing C1:C with the column with dates and E1:E with the column with numbers.

Comment: But I would like to do this with a script rather than operate from the spreadsheet

Comment: You could use this on a cell and get the value from there in script for now.

Comment: try instead of `if(dateOfEntry > threeMonthsAgo && dateOfEntry !== "") {` this `if(dateOfEntry > threeMonthsAgo && dateOfEntry != "") {` dateOfEntry could be different from string.

Comment: I think I solved the issue (corrected script in the next post). In the //loop over the values section, there should be an additional condition to exclude values which are blank values. Otherwise, any number after the blank values are appended as strings, giving results like 270148 (where individual values were 130, 140, "", "", 148). After the total value is obtained, this can be divided by the warning count which gives the average. However, I wonder if there is any way to shorten this script further.

Comment: // Loop over the values
   for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
     var dateOfEntry = dateOfEntryValues[i][0];
     if(dateOfEntry > threeMonthsAgo && dateOfEntry !== "" && Values[i][0] !== 0) {
   // if it's within 3 months ago, add the values.
   sumValues = sumValues + Values[i][0];
   warning_count++;                var averageValues = sumValues / warning_count;